# How does angularjs get version number from this directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How does angularjs get version number from this directive ......

```
    angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
  directive('appVersion', ['version', function(version) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      elm.text(version);
    };
  }])
```

Comment: Well, it's injected into the directive function. That means that `version` is an angular constant of value or service defined elsewhere.

Comment: ohhh i got dat ..its service defined....thnks ...so silly of me...

Comment: @JBNizet you should turn this comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`version` is injected into the directive function. That means that `version` is an angular constant or value or service defined elsewhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Check about [`Module.constant`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#methods_value) and [`Module.value`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#methods_value), it might be injected somewhere else.